# How to fire a method in aspx.cs file using ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services, jquery

I wanna **call a method** on **PersonalDetails.aspx.cs** page **using Ajax**. I have tried to it using following code. but it doesn't worked. 
**I just wanna fire the method included in the PersonalDetails.aspx.cs** How do i do it? :)
Can somebody help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input").keydown(function () {
            $("input").css("background-color", "yellow");
        });
        $("input").keyup(function () {
            $("input").css("background-color", "pink");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "PersonalDetails.aspx/GetFarmersByName",
                data: { name: +request.term },
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    return data;
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is The method I wanna fire..

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public  bool GetFarmersByName(string name)
    {
        _personalData = new personalData();
        int cky = 45;
        CdMa cdMas = new CdMa();
        cdMas = _personalData.getcdMasByConcdCd2(cky, "AdrPreFix", true);
        int prefixKy = cdMas.CdKy;

        List<FMISPersonalDataViewByName_Result> list = new List<FMISPersonalDataViewByName_Result>();

        list = _personalData.GetPersonalDataByName(prefixKy, cky, name);

        if (list != null)
        {
            grvPersonalData.DataSource = list;
            grvPersonalData.DataBind();
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: You were missing 
1) static keyword 
2) jquery data property is not well formed 
      data: "{'name': '" + request.term + "'}"

Comment: When I put static it's shows an error called "The object reference required for non-static field method or property.." with highlighting "grvPersonalData".

Comment: You won't be able to bind data grid from code-behind while making AJAX call. Also, won't able to use non static field in static method. Can you post the full aspx source code?

Answer (score 2):

Aarif Qureshi answer should be the accepted one.

If you run what you're running, chances are you're getting "**{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive:...**"? It looks like your data object is malformed, it should be data: "{...}" OR data: JSON.stringify({ ... })

(*which by the way was also incorrect - and it was already pointed out*)

Answer (score 0):

please make your method GetFarmersByName to public static bool GetFarmersByName  and try to debug the code

and change following

`data: "{name: " + request.term + "}"`   ,

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public  bool GetFarmersByName(string name)
```

this method must be public static method which return some data if you want to call it by ajax..

like

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static bool GetFarmersByName(string name)
```

Comment: When I put static it's shows an error called "The object reference required for non-static field method or property" with highlighting "grvPersonalData".